# Generate report in Text File in tabular format - c# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, report, rdlc

Is there any way in C# .Net to generate a report in a text file? The data should be arranged in tabular format?

RDLC can generate report in pdf or Excel but specifically to text file is my requirement. The columns can be separated by spaces or any other special character.

Comment: (1) Should the columns have constant width? (2) If not, how should the separator character be escaped if it happens to be inside some column text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you tried Crystal Report it can exporting the reports to csv and text.

see:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25342/Convert-Query-Result-into-CSV-TXT-XLS-or-Fill-Into

Greetings

Comment: It seems helpful.. Let me try this one. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, You have to do it manually, may be you can use a `|` as a separator to make it resemble in a tabular format.

However, you can opt to use the `.csv` format so that it can be read using both Excel or notepad like text file reader.

Comment: The requirement is I have to put all data that is coming from database in a text file with rows and columns.
I can use RDLC to generate report in Excel or PDF or CSV. But it has to be in Notepad in text format with proper formatting done.

Comment: As I have said, you will manually have to generate the .txt file with the contents. you can use `\t` or 'VbTab` for giving spaces between cell values.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the file myself.
Here is a reference:

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/anandctutorials/article.php/c5861/Working-with-Files-in-C.htm